# Can't add to DOM content before page load Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, parse-platform

I am currently trying to add a bunch of elements to a list using javscript after querying from parse.

I am able to get the full list if I don't add any click listeners, however if I do add click listeners, only the first 5 items appear in the list.

Here is the code in my javascript file, it is called first in the html:

```
if (!Parse.User.current()){
    window.location.href = 'index.html';
}
else {
    getParticipants();
}

$( document ).ready(function() {


$('#sign-out').click(function(){
    Parse.User.logOut();
    window.location.href = 'index.html';
    });
```

});

```
function getParticipants (){
var Participants = Parse.Object.extend("Participants");
var query = new Parse.Query(Participants);
query.ascending("patientID");
query.find({
    success: function(results) {
        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
            var object = results[i];
            var id = object.get("patientID");
            $(".list-group").append("<li class='list-group-item' id='" + id + "'>" + id + "</li>");
            (function (id) {
                $('#' + object.get("patientID")).click(function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();

                    if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
                        localStorage.setItem("patientID", id);
                    } else {
                        // Sorry! No Web Storage support..
                    }

                    window.location = 'profile.html';
                });
            }(id));
        }
    },
    error: function(error) {
        alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
    }
});
```

}

Comment: So why are you not doing it on document ready?

Comment: I moved the getParticipants() function to run on document ready and it still only displays 5 items. Any ideas?

Comment: Is there an error in the console? Without seeing it running and knowing the data, it is rather impossible to debug. My guess is you have an error.

Comment: You were right, it had to do with an id that contained invalid symbols. Thanks for your help guys!

Comment: @edbert and yet, you accepted an answer that has nothing to do with the invalid symbols, and on top of that is wrong — you do **not** have to wait until `onload` to manipulate the DOM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can never modify the DOM before the page loads because at that point the DOM isn't ready.

Any DOM manipulation should be done after onload event is fired.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I moved the function into the onload event, however it is still only displaying 5 results. However when I remove the click listeners it displays all of them

Comment: `onload` fires after **everything** is loaded, including images etc. You can manipulate the DOM after [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded), so it should work in your `$(document).ready(...)` function.